# How to change MapTypeid in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to change the map type from RoadMap to Hybrid when a user clicks on a marker (it automatically zoom's and center's on it already)

I can't find anything on Google's API documentation for 3.2 on how to do that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call *setMapTypeId* on your [map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object:

```
setMapTypeId(mapTypeId:MapTypeId)
```

where [mapTypeId](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId) is HYBRID.